# How to install Windows 10 feature updates one by one?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am using Windows 10 EN on a Dell XPS 13. I tend to install updates as soon as Windows asks me to but I've realized that it was not getting feature updates for some time. Don't know why and actually not important at this point. I am on 1803 and the latest is 1909.

I've tried installing the update through windows update and failed several times. Tried everything Windows Update Troubleshooter recommended, no luck. Contacted MS Support, they directed me to update with an ISO file, still failure.

MS Support says the latest update is 1909 and since I missed many major updates, I am having this problem. I should give up on trying an in-place update, backup my files and install a clean 1909. I don't want to do that.

The question is: How can I install feature updates since 1803 one-by-one, manually (1809, then 1903, then 1909) ?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1497744/how-to-update-windows-10-thats-nearing-the-end-of-support-but-says-it-is-up-to/1497748#1497748

Comment: What happened when you tried the inplace upgrade with the ISO? Did you do it [this way](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)?

Comment: If you want to install 1809, 1903, and 1909 you would need to download each ISO and upgrade Windows using the ISO.  What part of that process are you stuck on?

Comment: Where do you get each ISO?

Comment: @harrymc, those are the exact steps MS Support walked me through. Still error. Upgrade fails and rolls back. Error Code: 0x8007001f

Comment: @Ramhound I've downloaded MediaCreationTool1909.exe from Microsoft site and the tool created an ISO for me. I don't know how to get the ISO's for earlier versions.

Comment: During the ISO upgrade, the process starts, PC restarts several times and gets stuck at some point. About 20 mins later restarts again, during boot it says "Rolling back changes to your computer" and Windows 10 1803 starts.

Comment: @e-mre - There is an existing question with several different methods to download Windows 10 ISOs.  What research have you done with regards to that problem?

Comment: @Ramhound - I was staying away from non-MS sites for getting images so far but I am relaxing that principle now. Desparate times, desparate measures.

Comment: Every solution proposed in that duplicate is downloading directly from Microsoft.  If you want to click a link on a Microsoft website that requires a MSDN or similar subscription.  Which is a waste of money if your not a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 0x8007001f is with Windows Update.

I would suggest to check your existing installation with the commands:

```
chkdsk
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
sfc /scannow
```

Try also to troubleshoot Windows Update via
*Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update >
Run the troubleshooter*.

If this does not help, perform first an in-place upgrade of Windows 10 to itself
using the same version as is installed. This might reset the components to
a correct state.

EDIT

Microsoft no longer lets download older Windows 10 releases as it did
[in the past](https://pureinfotech.com/download-windows-10-1803-iso-file-after-1809-releases/).
But they can still be downloaded from the
[TechBench site](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/).

The poster was still blocked, and found out that the problem was that
his user profile was not on the C drive. When the profile was moved back to C,
the two upgrades finally succeeded.

Comment: How do I perform first an in-place upgrade of Windows 10 to itself ?

Comment: See [this link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). The real trick will be to get a [1803 ISO](https://pureinfotech.com/download-windows-10-1803-iso-file-after-1809-releases/).

Comment: Exactly ... That's what I'm trying to do. The way to get the ISO described in the link you sent can now get only 1909, no earlier versions.

Comment: Look better into the second link.

Comment: I did. It tricks microsoft.com into thinking that you are a non-windows client so it allows you to download the ISO but that doesn't work. The dropdown shows only November 2019 release.

Comment: Right, this trick doesn't work anymore. Try the [TechBench site](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/).

Comment: TechBench seems to have multiple images for each build. Are they all stable builds ?

Comment: Never used this website, but it is well-referenced. If you choose type "Windows (Final)" it should give the released version.

Comment: For what reason was this answer downvoted?

Comment: Don't know. Not me.

Comment: OK, It took me some time and several failed attempts but I managed to update my windows to 1909. It turns out (I found this info buried deep in a forum) windows update does not like it when the user profile is on a drive other than C: and fails while migrating. I moved my profile to C and the update completed without a problem. (Kind of ... I ruined my profile while moving). Anyways, as far as the original question is concerned, you directing me to TechBench provided what I asked in this question so I will accept your answer.